# User cannot use his last five passwords

Tags: mysql

I want to have a user management system. I allow users to change their password, but I should have restrictions. For instance that the new password is not any of the last five passwords used.

How should I maintain a list of the last five passwords?

Comment: You probably shouldn't. Unless you are in the military strict regiments like this usually result in worse security.

Comment: i dont think that you should do that users dont like to have many restrictions specialy when it comes to thier passwords

Comment: You can add five different columns for passwords as `pwd1, pwd2, pwd3, pwd4, pwd5` and put validation logic in stored procedure.

Comment: @Omesh If you do that, you'll have to rotate them up a column each time the password changes - it'll get annoying to program that.

Comment: Not afraid about some user could save a new password five times a day and return afterwards to the old one? :)

Comment: @DelPedro I've done that once on an irritating site that blocked me this way.

Comment: That is a problem I know from many users - they even think they are more clever than the computer. This often happens whenever the application is to rigid. Often it helps to to display a Message: "You did not change you password for 300 days - please read her why this is a great security problem blah"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I already posted a comment above. But just to answer your question. You should create an `old_passwords` table with the `user_id`, `old_password`, `creation_date` in it.

Store the date when the password is first created in the main table. When changing the password copy the old password and that original date to `creation_date` in the `old_passwords` table. Then update the password, and set the date to now in the main user table.

You should also probably drop a unique index on `user_id, creation_date`.

To delete:

```
DELETE FROM old_password
WHERE user_id = ## AND creation_date NOT IN
  (SELECT creation_date
   FROM old_password
   WHERE user_id = ##
   ORDER BY creation_date DESC
   LIMIT 5)
```

(You should test this code BTW.) You run this query when a person updates their password.

Comment: I suppose it may be worth mentioning that passwords should be stored encrypted in this table as well. )

Comment: How could they _not_ be stored encrypted? :) if he can retrieve the password _then_ insert it, then the password isn't (good) encrypted to begin with.

Comment: @Ariel -  i have a small doubt. whats the datatype of column and say when he updates his password for 7th time, how will i delete the 1st and second password ?

Comment: The datatype of the `old_password` column is the same as the `password` column in the main table of course. The `creation_date` in both the `old_password` and the main table are both `timestamp`. To delete I'll post a query for you. And I can not believe you are actually doing this - users will not like it.

Comment: unique key is not good, 'cause maybe the user forgets his new password and uses the "forgot your password?" link to get a new password the same day

Comment: @DelPedro It's a timestamp - it include the time, down to the second.